# Bitcoin QR code on a product sold in stores

Tags: qrcode

How and which company do i turn to implement a QR code for bitcoin on a product sold within stores.

Comment: What do you expect a ‘QR code for bitcoin’ to do exactly? It’s not clear to me what you’re asking.

Comment: what company/website do i go too..to download a QR (BTC) code? To have on products.

Comment: I want the QR code for products. too accept bitcoin payments.

Comment: Basically generating my own code.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a bitcoin payment address (in QR code format, or otherwise) is generally not the way to accept bitcoin for a sale. There would be very basic vulnerabilities, such as having someone swap the payment address displayed on your product, etc. Attempting to use the same address on every product is bad for privacy/fungibility, and it makes backend accounting difficult.

Accepting Bitcoin for payments is best done using a bitcoin payment processor such as BTCPayServer (an open source project), or for small scale you could even process payments manually at the till. In either case, customers would be presented with a payment address during checkout, *not* a payment address per product.